# Microsoft Sql Management Studio layout is brocken

Tags: windows, ssms

MSSQL studios layout was brocken after i was used laptop without additional monitor. Resolution changes does not helps.I have windows 10

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of SSMS are you using? It doesn't look like [SSMS 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms), have you tried installing the latest version?

Answer (score -1):

Problem was solved. I notice that in display settings was

"Some apps won't respond to scaling changes until you sing out"

When i sign out and changed scaling and resolution problem was solved